# AlphaBot2 run / migrate to .NET Core

Tags: wheeled-robot

Bought this robot called AlphaBot2. Has sample code here:
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:AlphaBot_Demo.7z

What I am interested in knowing is how do I convert these Python samples to C# with .NET Core to run on Windows 10 Iot.

Look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: why don't you find examples written for Win 10 IOT?

Comment: Do the Python examples work on Windows IoT Python? You may want to get that to work, and understand how they work, before you try porting them to a new language.